# How do I fix the error "myelement" does not contain definition for AddRange

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 tables with a question and a child question. I pretty much just want to get all the parent questions and all the child questions and put them together in like a list to serve to the front end. I have this code

I tried to make them both a list or `IEnumerable` - neither is working

```
IEnumerable<KPMProjectChecklistParentQuestion> ParentQuestions = DataServiceLocator.GetKPMProjectChecklistParentQuestions_DAO().GetAll(Context).Where(x => x.Active);

IEnumerable<KPMProjectChecklistChildQuestion> ChildQuestions = DataServiceLocator.GetKPMProjectChecklistChildQuestions_DAO().GetAll(Context).Where(x => x.Active);

ViewBag.Questions = ParentQuestions.AddRange(ChildQuestions);
```

I just want `ViewBag.Questions` to have both parent and child questions available.

Comment: `Concat` is (roughly) the `IEnumerable` equivalent of `List`'s `AddRange`.

Comment: does not contain a definitions of concat best extension of queryable concat requires a recieviable type of iquerable  even changed Prentquestion, and child question to List<object> query.tolist() I can't addrange.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2 - you'll need to ensure the types of the two things being concatted is the same (e.g. use `Cast<object>().Concat(`).